# Why won't my app ask permission to use the microphone?

Tags: swift, avaudioengine

Working on a recording app. So I started from scratch, and basically jump right into recording. I made sure to add the Privacy - Microphone Usage Description string.

What strikes me as odd, is that the app launches straight into recording. No alert comes up the first time asking the user for permission, which I thought was the norm.

Have I misunderstood something?

```
override func viewDidLoad()   {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   record3()
}

func record3()   {
    print ("recording")
    let node = audioEngine.inputNode
    let recordingFormat = node.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
    var silencish = 0
    var wordsish  = 0
    makeFile(format: recordingFormat)

    node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 8192, format: recordingFormat, block: {
           [self]
           (buffer, _) in

        do {
               try audioFile!.write(from: buffer);
               x += 1;
               if x > 300 {
                   print ("it's over sergio")
                   endThis()
               }
           } catch {return};})
    
    audioEngine.prepare()
    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch let error {
        print ("oh catch \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it actually recording anything?

Comment: By the way, try to stop using unnecessary semicolons.

Answer (score -1):

Even the simulators remember if you authorized microphone usage before, they **won't ask again**. If you want them to, **delete** and **reinstall** the app.

**If that's not the case:**

I never used microphone in a swift app, but I do have some experience with working with iOS permissions. For example, when I worked with location, I used a function that request permission from user:

```swift
class ContentModel: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, ObservableObject {
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    func requestGeolocationPermission() {
        
        // Request permission from the user
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}
```

Can't something similar be applied in your case?

**Try**:

Declare the permission request function

```swift
func requestRecordPermission(_ response: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)
```

And then request permission to record.

```swift
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission { granted in
    if granted {
        // The user granted access. Present recording interface.
    } else {
        // Present message to user indicating that recording
        // can't be performed until they change their preference
        // under Settings -> Privacy -> Microphone
    }
}
```

This is from Apple Developer documentation, here's the link if you wanna do some further reading: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/1616601-requestrecordpermission

Comment: I did the whole delete and erase contents of the simulators

Comment: Okay, I'm going through Apple Developer documentation now. If I find something, I'll get back to you m8! https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/1616601-requestrecordpermission

Comment: Updated the answer, hope it helps!

Comment: Have to say, am using AVAudioEngine, so I have no instance of AVAudioSession. Also, when I first started this, I built it as above, and the iOS would ask me.  It no longer does

Comment: Update, on phone it asks, as it should. Not on simulator. Even when I use a new device. So maybe I shouldn't be so worried?

Comment: Functionality on a phone is crucial, simulators can be sometimes trouble. I'd say all good!